# Set Large Text from Accessibility for only one screen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, wayland

I am using `ubuntu-22.10` with Wayland. I am facing issues setting the display settings of my laptop and monitors. I am using two external monitors and my laptop display. Their highest resolution is as follows:

1. Laptop -> 2560 x 1600 (16:10)
2. Monitor-1 -> 1920 x 1200 (16:10)
3. Monitor-2 -> 1920 x 1200 (16:10)

Both text size and display for the external monitors are very ideal for me. For the laptop display, however, in the highest resolution, the text is quite small and not very ideal for me.

So, what I want to do is to increase the text size for just the laptop display. The `Large Text` `Accessibility` setting increases the text size for all displays. When I enable large text at the `1.25` factor, the laptop display comes to an ideal level, but the monitor display/text becomes too large for me.

I tried lowering the resolution of my laptop display as well. I dropped to `1920 x 1200`. With this, the text size is at an ideal level but the text is quite blurry and feels very dizzying and annoying.

So, the ideal scenario for me would be to enable `Large Text` just for the laptop display. Is it possible to achieve this? Or, what other alternatives do I have?

Thanks.

Edit: Also, fractional scaling just for the laptop display is not an option for me because when I set the fractional scaling to `1.25` for the laptop, I am again faced with the blurry text issue.

Comment: hi, did you find any solution to your problem ? Kinda the same issue here

Comment: @FlorentDestremau Hey. Nope, haven't found a solution yet. Currently, I am setting the large text scaling to `1.15` and compromising the ideal balance.

Comment: I think my solution will be to at last upgrade to a 4K monitor to keep with the frame.work screen